Office, Open Source, simple markdown editor
I would like to write on a offline, open source, simple and effective markdown editor. And I want to be able to have a "preview" of my document like if it was rendered like an GitHub README

Strictly FOSS, or is paid OK? Platform? Would an add-on to a word processor that saves-as Markdown be acceptable? Which dialects of Markdown do you want support for (e.g., original, CommonMark, Github-flavored, etc.)?

There are a a number of possibilities these include;

Notepad++ with one of the markdown plug-ins such as MarkdownViewer++ is free, open source GPL, supports multiple programming languages. MS-Windows Only.
Emacs with one of several markdown viewers, free, open source bit of a pain to install on windows.
If you are into the Python world then you can pip install jupyterlab  and then run jupyter lab and work in a browser window with cells containing a mixture of markdown, python (and other languages) and the results of running the code in those cells.
Visual Studio Code both comes with a markdown editing, navigator Navigator Outline, snippets & previewer (Ctrl-K V for side by side preview) and has a number of plug-ins available. The Doc Writer Profile Template installs a good selection of plug-in components. Free & mostly open source cross platform. (File->Preferences->Profiles->From Templates (in the drop-down)->Doc Writer -> Create) .

There are many other options that you might like to take a look at.
